# Override value in another file in hydra

Tags: yaml, overriding, config, fb-hydra, hydra

I have the following files:

```
├── callbacks
│   ├── default.yaml
│   ├── early_stopping.yaml
│   └── finetuning.yaml
├── model
│   ├── model_1.yaml
│   └── model_2.yaml
└── train.yaml
```

train.yaml

```
defaults:
  - _self_
  - model: model_1
  - callbacks: default
```

callbacks/default.yaml

```
defaults:
  - finetuning
  - early_stopping
  - _self_
```

callbacks/finetuning.yaml

```
finetuning:
  _target_: callbacks.custom_finetuning.CustomFinetuning
  unfreeze_at_epoch: null
  refreeze_at_epoch: null
```

model_1.yaml

```
_target_: models.Model_1
```

I want override `unfreeze_at_epoch` and `refreeze_at_epoch` from model_1.yaml and model_2.yaml so that each model can have different values.
I tried adding the following but it does not work:

```
callbacks:
  finetuning:
    unfreeze_at_epoch: 125
    refreeze_at_epoch: 350
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config group for `model/model_1.yaml` is model, meaning that by default all the config values defined there are under the model node.
You can change that using the [package directive](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/overriding_packages/).
In this case, by setting package header to `_global_`.

e.g, model_1.yaml can become:

```yaml
# @package _global_

model:
  _target_: models.Model_1
callbacks:
  finetuning:
    unfreeze_at_epoch: 125
    refreeze_at_epoch: 350
```

A few other things to note is that you config composition order, controlled by the `_self_` keyword in the defaults list is correct.
You can learn more about it [here](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/defaults_list/#composition-order).

Finally, you may want to use the pattern of [configuring experiments](https://hydra.cc/docs/patterns/configuring_experiments/).

Comment: Thank for your reply! This seems to work, but only if you don't define the `finetuning` in the file callbacks/default.yaml . This is okay with me. However, do you know why it won't work in that situation? If I define the `finetuning` in callbacks/default.yaml, then the value won't be overwritten by the model_1.yaml

Comment: `callbacks/default.yaml` defauls list has `_self_` as the last element. This means it's overriding whatever is defined by the defaults list. See https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/defaults_list/#composition-order